# Route 2 external IP ranges using pfSense

Tags: networking, linux-networking, pfsense

I have pfSense running on some hardware routing my /27 block of IP addresses assigned by my ISP. I asked for and got another /26 block that I want to send all of the block to a single server (it will have 62 virtual interfaces). The problem is now I am completly lost.

Let's say the address range of the new IPs is 216.1.2.0 and the box I am routing to is 192.168.1.10. I set a NAT of 216.1.2.0 -> 192.168.1.10

Nothing. I can't get to it, I can't get out from the .10 box to the internet. I can get to other boxes on the 192.168 network. If I NAT an address from the original /27 block to .10 it works like a champ.

I'm enough of a newbie that I am now stuck. Do I need to set up a virtual IP? At this point I'm not even sure what questions to ask so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you got 3 physical cards on you computer(lan and 2x Wan)? Or you have just one WAN and one Lan and on the WAN you have multiple vLans?

Comment: @Rat2000 Two cards. One WAN and one LAN. I have two blocks routed to the same modem (which feeds the WAN port of the pfSense box).